# Отсортировать таблицы в определенном порядке

Tags: sql, база-данных, access

Есть 12 таблиц с каждым месяцем года, через этот запрос выводится список этих таблиц, но нужно отсортировать их по дате т.е. январь, февраль и т.д. А пока выводится только в алфавитном порядке, как строго указать в каком порядке должны выводиться таблицы.

```
SELECT mSysObjects.Name
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (Left$([Name],1)<>"~") And (Left$([Name],1)<> "_") And (MSysObjects.Type)=5
```

Так не работает

```
SELECT mSysObjects.Name
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (Left$([Name],1)  <> "~" ) And (Left$([Name],1)  <> "_" ) And  (MSysObjects.Type)=5
ORDER BY FIELD (mSysObjects.Name, "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь")
```

Comment: Добавьте вычисляемый столбец, который будет ставить в соответствие месяцу его номер. Но этому столбцу и сортируйте.

Comment: хорошая идея, спасибо

Comment: только как в mSysObjects добавить столбец, и я не думаю что это хорошая идея) как варант, поробую поле ID править

Comment: Не в таблицу, а в запрос, используя функцию IIF.

Comment: IIF будет слишком громоздко. Switch лучше подойдет. А еще лучше табличку с соответствием названия и номера добавить, связать ее с существующим запросом, по номеру и сортировать.